# How do I save the vector n into a file called <02_exercises_vector3.txt> such that each letter is on one line?

Tags: r

How do I  save the vector n into a file called <02_exercises_vector3.txt> such that each letter is on one line? I just need some help understanding this. I am brand new to R and am trying to get a base understanding but it is very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, using `cat` with the `file` parameter:

```
> n <- letters[1:10]
> n
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
> cat(n,file="foo.txt",sep="\n")
```

Look at `?cat`.